# approximately order zero maps

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I have Googled the definition, but I cannot get the satiafactory result.
What is the precise definition of the approximately order zero maps?[image]

Comment: Did you download any of the PDFs of the articles found with Google? Did they contain the definition you are looking for?

Comment: Yes , I downloaded one . But it does not give the exact definition.

Comment: Yes, and there are other PDFs. Did you download all of them?

Comment: Can you motivate this question?  Where did you see the notion of approximately order zero map arise, without a definition being given?

Comment: @Aweygan， the notion appeared in the first paragraph of the proof of Pro 5

Comment: They don't mention a reference, so I would just assume it means that the sequence $(\eta_i)_i$ perserves orthogonality in the limit, i.e., if $a,b\in B$ are positive and $ab=0$, then $\lim_i\eta_i(a)\eta_i(b)=0$.